# how to add IOBluetooth framework to Xcode

Tags: ios, iobluetooth

I use Xcode 5.1.1 and tried to add IOBluetooth framework but couldn't find it. 
I found the coreBluetooth frame only. How do I find it? is it not supported any more?

Answer (score 2):

IOBluetooth is used by MAC OS only. If you are developing for iOS you have to use CoreBluetooth.

Comment: first thank you for this info. Secondly, Is it possible to build an app that simply detects any bluetooth device? without setting the central and the peripheral.

Comment: @user2066392 There is the only one way on iOS to scan for devices - using CBCentralManager. If you need a sample - there are tons of them on GitHub. I can suggest to use this one - https://github.com/winkapp/BlocksBluetooth . It is also a block-based wrapper around CoreBluetooth.